# Find elements by attribute name and its value using XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Well, using .NET 3.5 and XDocument I am trying to find `<table class='imgcr'>` element. I created the code below but it crashes, of course, because `e.Attribute("class")` may be null. So... I have to put null check everywhere? This will double `e.Attribute("class")`. Not laconic solution at all.

```
XElement table =
    d.Descendants("table").
    SingleOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("class").Value == "imgcr");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure you exception is thrown because you `table` element may come without `class` attribute, then you could do this instead:

```
XElement table =
    d.Descendants("table").
    SingleOrDefault(e => ((string)e.Attribute("class")) == "imgcr");
```

In that case you are casting a `null` value to `string`, which is `null` at the end, so you are comparing  `null == "imgcr"`, what is `false`.

You can check this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387056.aspx) if you need more info about how to retrieve the value of an attribute. There you will find this affirmation:

> You can cast an `XAttribute` to the desired type; the explicit
>   conversion operator then converts the contents of the element or
>   attribute to the specified type.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is quite short

```
XElement table =
  d.Descendants("table").
    SingleOrDefault(e => { var x = e.Attribute("class"); return x==null ? false: x.Value == "imgcr";});
```

this is shorter (but not much -- unless you can re-use t variable.)

```
XAttribute t = new XAttribute("class","");
XElement table =
  d.Descendants("table").
    SingleOrDefault(e => (e.Attribute("class") ?? t).Value == "imgcr");
```